# Could not find class xxx$1 referenced from method xxx.yyy android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I created app and it was working well, then I changed the package name of the app, then I got this errors

```
04-28 09:45:49.604  31707-31707/? E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.HomeFragment', referenced from method xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem
04-28 09:45:49.604  31707-31707/? E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.SelectUserFragmentDialog', referenced from method xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem
04-28 09:45:49.609  31707-31707/? E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.AskServiceFragment', referenced from method xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem
04-28 09:45:49.609  31707-31707/? E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.ServicesFragment', referenced from method xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem
04-28 09:45:49.609  31707-31707/? E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.VideosFragment', referenced from method xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem
04-28 09:45:49.609  31707-31707/? E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.TipsFragment', referenced from method xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem
04-28 09:45:49.609  31707-31707/? E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.ContactUSFragment', referenced from method xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem
04-28 09:45:49.609  31707-31707/? E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.AskServiceResults', referenced from method xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem
04-28 09:45:49.614  31707-31707/? E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment$1', referenced from method xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView
04-28 09:45:49.614  31707-31707/? E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment$3', referenced from method xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp
04-28 09:45:49.664  31707-31707/? E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.HomeFragment
        at xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:402)
        at xxx.yyy.zzz.carcleaningapp.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:122)
```

Althought, all of the are found in the project folder as showing in the screenShot

[image]

Comment: have you tried to the clean build? Android Studio should complain before building if those classes aren't there.

Comment: I do clean many times but still give me this error